# What is this gray bird that has black stripes on the side and around the head?

Tags: birds, bird-identification

The bird in this picture is mostly gray but has black and white stripes on the flank area. It also has a white head, red beak and red-rimmed eye. The head is outlined with a black stripe which goes across the face.

What is the name of the bird?

[image: A bird to be identified]

<sub>From [Wikibird](http://wikibird.blog.ir/1393/06/05/%DA%A9%D8%A8%DA%A9) - © Morteza Nemati</sub>

Comment: Olin - while your core message is correct (location, time, behaviour etc is required) please remember that wording it like that comes across as rather rude and brusque.

Comment: Given context and a rough description this could be salvaged, maybe check these similar questions that are on topic: [What is this fish that looks like a common roach with black eyes and red gills?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/14277/what-is-this-fish-that-looks-like-a-common-roach-with-black-eyes-and-red-gills) & [Help identifying black and white “square winged” bird?](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8372/help-identifying-black-and-white-square-winged-bird). Notice they include descriptions of the animals in text and location information, etc.

Comment: Kim, I edited the most out of your question, but you really should consider adding any information that you have. Describe the picture like "the bird has a red beak" and so on. Check out this question as reference and help: http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8372/help-identifying-black-and-white-square-winged-bird While writing a question keep in mind what others might search for. If they see this bird, they are not going to type "a bird in the picture below" but rather "a bird with a red beak (...)".

Answer (score 7):

According to [this page](http://pakistanpaedia.com/wildlife/birds/bird-watching-in_pakistan.html) (cache [here](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:prhLRpC2VXEJ:pakistanpaedia.com/wildlife/birds/bird-watching-in_pakistan.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=mx)) it's a Chukar partridge (Alectoris chukar):

> The Chukar (Alectoris chukar) is a Eurasian upland game bird in the pheasant family Phasianidae of the order Galliformes, gallinaceous birds. Its native range in Asia from Pakistan and Kashmir, India and Afghanistan.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukar_partridge) also has an article about it:

> This partridge has well marked black and white bars on the flanks and a black band running from the forehead across the eye and running down the head to form a necklace that encloses a white throat. The species has been introduced into many other places and feral populations have established themselves in parts of North America and New Zealand. This bird can be found in parts of Middle East.

Answer (score 4):

That is a [Chukar partridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukar_partridge). For more information I would suggest the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chukar_partridge).